# Array type 'some_typedef_name' is not assignable

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, typedef

I have a two-dimensional array:

```c
(in a header file)
#define N 11
typedef char adjmat[N][N];
```

When I declare the array in the main function

```c
adjmat mat[N][N];
```

I can create the array with values

```c
adjmat mat[N][N] = {{1, 1, 1},{0, 0, 0}};
```

and read the values from the array

```c
char example = mat[0][0];
```

but when I try to assing a value to a cell in the array

```c
mat[i][j] = getchar() - '0';
```

I get an error:

`Array type 'adjmat' (aka 'char[11][11]') is not assignable`

how can I assign a value to the array's cells?

Comment: Did you mean to declare it as `adjmat mat;`? Otherwise, you create a four-dimensional array

Comment: When you define `mat` as `adjmat mat[N][N];`, you're really doing `char mat[N][N][N][N];`. Probably not what you want.

Comment: @Ctx, I meant to create a two-dimensional array. didn't know there is no need for the square brackets if already declared in typedef

Comment: Please do not abuse `typedef`. It should not be used as a fancy obfuscator to rename basic types, but only when it does add readability. Had you used directly `char mat[N][N] = ...`, you would not have any problem...

Comment: @SergeBallesta In general you are correct, but it depends on the context and overall code style/documentation if this can be considered an "abuse" of typedef here. It might be not.

Comment: @Ctx: I know, it. Typedefs highly help when using pointer to functions or pointer to know size arrays. But it is not a tool that I would advise for a beginner writing simple programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already typedef-ed the two dimensional array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 11
typedef char adjmat[N][N];


void foo()
{
    adjmat mat = {{1,2,3,}, {4,5,6,}, };

    for(int row = 0; row < N; row ++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < N; col++)
        {
            printf("%03d ", mat[row][col]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

if you declare

```
adjmat mat[N][N];
```

you declare the two-dimensional array of the two-dimensional arrays